# Is $f$ continuous?

Tags: gn.general-topology

The question is also posted [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373037/what-is-the-topology-the-author-used-which-make-t-is-metrizable)

The paper is Mizokami : [On characterizations of spaces with $G_\delta$-diagonals](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-50/issue-8/On-characterizations-of-spaces-with-G_delta-diagonals/10.3792/pja/1195518845.full)

See its Theorem 1, also you can see the picture . http://picpaste.com/a-eaiF4d3t.bmp.

> **Theorem 1:** A space $X$ has a $G_\delta$-diagonal iff there is an open mapping (single valued) $f$ from a metric space $T$ onto $X$ such that $$d(f^{-1}(p),f^{-1}(q))>0,$$ for distinct points $p, q \in X.$

The author defines $T$ as follows:

> **$T=\lbrace (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...)\in N(A): \bigcap \lbrace U_{\alpha_n}^n: n\in N\rbrace\not=\emptyset \rbrace$, where $\lbrace \mathcal U_n=\lbrace U_{\alpha}^n: \alpha \in A, n \in N\rbrace$ is a sequence of open covering of $X$ satisfying the condition in Lemma 1. (it can be seen in the paper.)**

The author defines $f: T \rightarrow X$ as follows:

> **$f(\alpha)=\bigcap \lbrace U_{\alpha_n}^n: n\in N \rbrace$ for $\alpha \in T$**

My question is this:

1. **What is the topology the author used which make $T$ is metrizable?**
2. **Is $f$ continuous?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As for the first question, isn't it answered in the paper? Otherwise you rather ask the author.

Comment: The author said unclearly in the paper.

Comment: Did you write her/him? I'd say it's be best solution. Even from my point of view it should be a step previous to publicly post a question like this.

Comment: Now I see that the paper is from 1974, so maybe the author is not available?

Comment: Yes. He may be very old.

Comment: Anyway, you can try, she/he may also be under 70, which is not very old, is it? :-S

Comment: I would edit the title of the question to ask about the topology rather than continuity of $f$, as the answer should be 'yes, it is continuous'.

Comment: The author mentions in the paper that he uses `Baire’s zero-dimensional metric space N(A).`
Baire space ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_%28set_theory%29 ) is well-known in the descriptive set theory, it has a basis consisting of sets of all sequences with prescribed first $n$ elements and we can get a metric by putting $d(x,y)=1/\min\{n; x_n\ne y_n\}$. I have seen it so far only for sequences of integers, but using other set $A$ instead of integers probably does not make much difference.

Comment: Baire space is just the set of functions from a countable set to another countable set, with a particular topology, so if $A$ is countable, there's your answer.

Comment: Why was this tagged special functions? I am going to remove this tag.

Comment: I don’t think $f$ needs to be continuous in general. Fix $X$ and $\mathcal U_n$, and construct $T$ and $f$ as in the proof. Then if we take $Y$ to be a finer topology than $X$ on the same underlying set, the same $\mathcal U_n$ can be used for $Y$, yielding the same $T$ and $f$. In particular, $Y$ can be taken discrete. Thus, if the construction as given always yielded a continuous $f$, the point preimages $f^{-1}(p)$ would need to be open (even clopen), and this does not appear to be the case.